# How do I prevent event bubbling with react-router-dom's <Link>?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

Okay. So I have something like this.

I added the Link around the whole post thinking I could just stop the bubbling for the individual buttons, but stopPropagation() is not working as expected.

I have split the button actions into a separate component, which was suggested by another post on the subject but that didn't do the trick. I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that the it's a react-router-dom Link, but it could be something else.

Any ideas?

```
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const MyComponent = ({
  doSomething
})=>(
  <Link to={`/some/url`}>
  <div className="post">
    <span className="button" onClick={e=>{
      e.stopPropagation();
      doSomething();
    }}>My Button</span>
  </div>
  </Link>
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

should work:

```
e.preventDefault()
```

more detailed explanation: [stopPropagation/preventDefault behavior on an element inside a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42379204/stoppropagation-preventdefault-behavior-on-an-element-inside-a-link)

Also, `stopPropagation` is a function, and it's waiting to be called.

Comment: Well that was easy! Thanks so much. This is pseudo-code so I actually did have stopPropagation called, but preventDefault was what I needed!